# What's the smallest LEGO component, based on its largest dimension?

Tags: piece-information, size, records

There's already [a question asking what the smallest component is](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/741/3176).

However, according to its answer, the smallest piece would be the [screwdriver](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6246a).
[image: Lego screwdriver]
It *is* pretty small, but its length is over 2 studs, perhaps even exactly three (I don't have one on hand to check). A regular 1x2 plate is smaller in that regard.

**What is the smallest piece measured by its largest dimension?**

---

The smallest I could come up with is the 1x1 round plate. Is there anything smaller?

[image: Round 1x1 Lego plate]

Comment: Either [this ring](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/512lUEN%2BphL._AC_UL320_SR282,320_.jpg) or [these coins](http://www.phantoms.su/data/VerSen/Pirates-of-the-Caribbean/4181/Caribbean_4181_5354.jpg) would seem a strong contender.

Comment: As would the "[Lever small](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4593#T=C)". I don't know their exact dimensions though.

Comment: @Valorum why not add these as an answer?

Comment: Or this one; http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24375#T=C&C=11

Comment: Because I don't know whether the dimensions/weights listed on bricklink are correct.

Comment: i think a lego friends crown would be the smallest piece like in comment 10. Or the bottom of a lever. I don't really think a screwdriver would be the smallest piece:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This tiny tiara piece](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23988#T=C&C=115) is smaller than the 1x1 round plate on all sides (middle piece in my image below).

[image: Lego tiara]

Comment: The piece appear in seven sets, so any of those could be used to compare the size to other elements. But it really is a tiny piece that is sometimes hard to make out on the pictures. Here are a couple of images that might be more helpful: http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=dp027s#T=S&O={} and http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41141-1#T=S&O={}

Comment: I also have the tiara myself, so if you really need an image against studs I can take a picture.

Comment: My daughter got some Friends sets this morning that had bows that seem about the same size as well.

Comment: Do you think you can add an image of it next to a 1×1 round plate?

Comment: I added my image to my answer as well. I put the tiara on a plate next to some other small items for reference.

Comment: I compared the tiara to the old style coins (with the denomination markings like 50 on them) and the tiara is < .5 mm shorter than their diameter. Without calipers, I can't be more accurate, but it supports your answer regardless.

Comment: Thanks for that. I also have to coins, but with such tiny elements it is hard to see miniscule differences.

Comment: I make the tiara about 6.8mm from your photo, but I added answer with a few of the other contenders as I have calipers and (access to) Friends sets.  These tiny pieces challenge the dexterity of children at the young end of the stated target age of the sets they come in

Comment: Since we are comparing only the largest dimension, I wonder the more spherical [Lever Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592) might be smaller than the length of the tiara.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to ask my vacuum cleaner, It might have escaped *me* ;).

It depends on what qualifies as "Lego component", though. Made by Lego for Lego would be one of the obvious restrictions, I assume. Is there a restriction on material? If not, it's probably hard to beat the smaller ones of the *stickers*, but I'd be reluctant to consider them as qualifying, probably because I always considered them more of a disfigurement of good bricks.

I would habe considered the evasive [1x1 glass pane](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=39glass#T=C&C=12) a near perfect candidate due to its 3rd dimension challenge, but that tiny tiara is hard to beat! Anyone able to compare both?

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen a sticker under 7mm in both dimensions though.  Now if the  question was about the *smallest* dimension, that would definitely be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this trigger component for stud-blasters may be even smaller than the tiara. I don't have a tiara though, so I can't check :( [Here is the piece](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15392&name=Minifig,%20Weapon%20Trigger%20for%20Gun,%20Blaster%20Mini&category=%5BMinifig,%20Weapon%5D#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

Comment: That trigger piece is actually just about twice as large as the tiara. I have both of them in front of me. The tiara is a very-very tiny piece. :)

Comment: Good to know! That thing must be incredibly small to be twice as small as the trigger. Sheesh!

Comment: I have added an image to my answer showing the tiara next to some other small pieces that people may be more familiar with. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a comment but for the need for pictures.

The Friends bow was listed as a possible contender, but it's a fair bit bigger than the tiara (which I don't have to show them side-by-side).

[image: Small Friends accessories].

The binoculars/robot head come in a touch smaller in the largest dimension, and the flower smaller still.  The bow is 12×10.5 mm, the binoculars 11.3×7.9 mm, and the flower 9.6 mm across.  Scaling off the photo in TheBrickBlogger's [answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8353/10569) the tiara is about 6.8 mm in both visible dimension.

[image: Small Friends accessories again]

As a comparison a minifig hand is 11 mm long, while a Friends microphone is 12.8 mm long

Answer (score 0):

I think the smallest piece is the [58176](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58176&C=95) pin piece from Captain Phasma; it's **super** small.

[image: 6030198 pin piece]

Comment: I think its smaller than the tiara

Comment: Its also a little smaller than a 1x1 small round plate

Comment: I think you ought to look closer at the tiara piece. The pin is not a regular 3.2mm pin, but even smaller (about 1.2mm). Besides, part [4770](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4770) is trivially smaller than [58176](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58176).

Comment: I guess you're right, the pin is about 3 millimeters bigger

Answer (score 0):

What about this one (4125253)?
It's a part of a Tallneck from Horizon: Forbidden West set. It's even smaller than 1x1 flat piece. [image]

Comment: That's [25269 1x1 tile quarter round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25269) and, for the purposes of this question, its largest dimension measures √2 ≃ 1.4 studs (same as the diagonal of a 1x1 square plate), which makes it *bigger* than a 1x1 round plate.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the smallest piece of Lego (not an accessory) would be a piece that is one stud square, and flat on top.
I'm looking at a white one right now, as I have nearly finished going through a gigantic pile of Lego from 1978-1982..

Comment: You mean a [1x1 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3070b)? The tiara from another answer is smaller than that.