# How can my daughter turn her horse into a unicorn?

Tags: customization, piece-usage, friends, connections

Short of gluing the horn to the purple bow, which fits in the horse’s forehead, is there a LEGO piece that would enable her to connect the horn to the horse?[image: Horse with wings]

Comment: I do not think LEGO has produced such a piece, and it makes sense why. Such a small connector would be prone to breaking off during play.

Comment: Is "Use a dremel" an acceptable answer? :)

Comment: @Pod. Is it ever not an acceptable answer?

Comment: I think I just discovered my new favourite SE site :D

Comment: Uhm, this "horse" has wings, and therefor u are asking "how to glue a horn to a PEGASUS"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A *[1x1 cone](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=78099#T=C&C=86)* with an inverted positioned *[screwdriver](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6246a&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Tool%20Screwdriver%20-%20Narrow%20Head&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C&C=10)* **just might** work here.

[image]

So, I'm saying *just might* based off the the halved cast line of Peggy's head.
[image]

The base peg of the horn/drill-bit would be too wide for the hole, but based off the cast fault line, which I hi-lighted in blue, there is a greater chance for the plastic halves to ease the slimmer screw driver in versus the blunter horn/drill-bit peg.  I don't have this Pegasus on hand, but... it *just might* work here.

This Pegasus first appeared last year and is in only [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=93083c01pb18&in=S).  I'm thinking the *LEGO* group just hasn't had the proper time to release a *FRIENDS*-line compatible accessory.

I see three choices:

1. We can gingerly test an illegal connection.
2. We can perform a Blasphemer's Lobotomy.
3. We can wait on *LEGO* to provide a piece.

***EDIT:***
While we wait for option three, let's play with what we got...

> [image] **PEGGA-BOO**!

Comment: I think the screw driver would be a little too wide, and rectangular.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I’m afraid you’re right.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Alas, I have to agree. I don't have the parts but I was curious, so I tried measuring the diameters based on the images in [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/8352) and [its answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8353). If I'm not mistaken, the hair accessories in the image (which I assume match the OP's bow) have a pin diameter of ~1.5 mm (I'd guess the holes are probably 1.6 mm) while the screwdriver shaft is ~1.8 mm (and the tip is a little wider yet). [Overlaying the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pilS.jpg) shows the size difference pretty clearly.

Comment: If the screw driver is too wide, you could always sand/cut it down a little.

Answer (score 15):

If the problem is that the base of the horn is too big to fit in the hole on the chanfron you have to make the former smaller or the latter bigger.  Careful work with a file/scalpel, if you're good at that kind of thing.  Remember that it's a lot easier to take a bit more off than to put a bit back.
Odd that the bow doesn't use a standard size stud anyway (walks away mumbling something about the old days).

Comment: Today I learned the word "chanfron" (armor for a horse's face).

Answer (score 13):

A possibility might be using *Horse Battle Helmet (unicorn)* parts [89524](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=89524) or [13745](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13745):

[image: horse helmet, red]
[image: horse helmet, gold]

However I'm unsure if those would fit. The head geometry of the horse part in question ([93083c01pb08](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93083c01pb08)) seems to be wider than the geometry of the horses in the castle sets (e.g. [10352c01pb03](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=10352c01pb03#T=C&C=11))

[image: horse head]

If you're not afraid to modify (cut and/or bend) one of the horse helmets, they might just fit.

---

P.S.: If it has wings it's not a horse but a pegasus. (I know, I'm nitpicking here)

Comment: Adding to your nitpick, if it has wings and a horn, it's an alicorn or pegacorn (depending on source material), not a unicorn.

Comment: More specifically, outside of My Little Pony, *alicorn* is **the horn** of a unicorn.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Well as long as we're nitpicking ;)... Using "pegasus" to refer to an entire species of flying horses rather than the specific Greek character, "Pegasus", is a more modern development. The "Narnia" books, for example, call such creatures simply "winged horses". So, really the more generic term would be "winged unicorn" rather than "pegacorn" (again, depending on source material).

Comment: A "pegacorn" is a pegasus with a horn. A creature so exceedingly rare it doesn't even exist in mythology. Not to confused with an alicorn, a unicorn with wings.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can drill it. Slowly, by hand. You want to end up with a 1/8 inch bit, but I found it easier to step up using a couple of smaller bits to get there. The bit doesn’t need to go in very far when you’re drilling.

It’s certainly not for purists, but it suits my kids just fine

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed by the fact how close 1/8 inch (3.175 mm) size is to an officially known diameter of 3.18 mm "bar". Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like there's currently any way to make this connection by normal means.

While there are quite a few parts with similar 1.6 mm attachment holes as your daughter's horse has (including some mildly surprising ones like [this ladybug](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93081b&name=Friends%20Accessories%20Beetle%20/%20Ladybug%20with%20Stud%20Holder&category=%5BFriends%5D#T=C)), parts with the matching pins seem to be relatively few.  Basically all of them seem to be small ornaments like [minifigure plumes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=plume&brand=1000&cat=636&tab=P#T=P) and [other headgear accessories](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=with+pin&brand=1000&cat=636&tab=P#T=P), including some [Friends accessories](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=with+pin&brand=1000&cat=771&tab=P#T=P) like your bow.  And as far as I can tell, none of them are really suited for attaching further parts.

Screwdrivers, as [suggested](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/13069) by Rin Rio-Oki, probably won't fit: the shaft is slightly too thick, as you can see in [this composite photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pilS.jpg).  The tips of [flower stems](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3741&name=Plant%20Flower%20Stem&category=%5BPlant%5D#T=C) *might* fit, but even if that worked, it'd just look totally ridiculous.

So you'll probably have to resort to some "blasphemous" methods.  In that respect, I see two options worth considering:

1. Filing the base of your unicorn horn down to about half of its original diameter, as [suggested](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/13073) by BlokeDownThePub, should let it fit into the hole.  It'll be tedious and fiddly work, and you could easily end up ruining the part entirely if you're not careful, but with practice it should be doable.  Of course, this also means that you won't be able to use the horn for its original purpose any more — although there are plenty of parts that should be able to make the connection in *that* direction, like the [Round 1x1 with Bar and Pin Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=20482&name=Tile,%20Round%201%20x%201%20with%20Bar%20and%20Pin%20Holder&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=C).
2. You could glue the horn to a part that already has a suitable pin, as you yourself suggest.  While you *could* use the bow you already have for this purpose, I'd suggest trying a [Star with Pin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93080f&name=Friends%20Accessories%20Hair%20Decoration,%20Star%20with%20Pin&category=%5BFriends%5D#T=C) accessory instead:

   [image: LEGO part 93080f Friends Accessories Hair Decoration, Star with Pin (Bright Light Orange)]

   If the 3D models are anywhere near accurate, the base of the horn ought to just fit inside the star (although not all of it; it's too long).  Alas, it probably won't *stay* in without glue, but at least it may *almost* look like a legitimate connection.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very late to the game here, but why can't we use the existing hole as a guide for an appropriately sized drill bit, converting it from Friends accessory size to standard LEGO horn size? If you drilled it slowly by hand, it would be really hard to mess it up.

Comment: @mindstormsboi, can you stop making nonsensical and quite rude edits to other peoples answers?

Comment: I see coule of issues here: 1) drilling isn't a solution for purists; 2) not sure if such drill bit exist to create a hole of 3.18 mm in diameter.